# Python multiprocessing closes too early

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I'm trying to integrate multiprocessing into a project but I can't get it working.
This is what I've got:

```
import time
import winsound
from multiprocessing import Process
winsound.MessageBeep()
def pr1():
    while 1:
        winsound.MessageBeep()
        time.sleep(0.5)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=pr1, args=())
    p.start()
    p.join()

while 1:
    print('hey')
```

but if I run it i hear only one beep and i want it to repeat. How do I get this done?

oke plan b,
I've got this now and I only get correct:

```
import time
import winsound
from multiprocessing import Process
def pr1():
    while 1:
        winsound.MessageBeep()
        print('its working') 
        time.sleep(0.5)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('correct')
    p = Process(target=pr1, args=())
    p.start()
    p.join()

while 1:
    print('hey')
```

So there is something wrong with with the creating of the process.
Any ideas?

Comment: if `__name__ == '__main__':` works?

Comment: I'm not on Windows, so cannot check it, but it looks like it should work. What happens if you add a print statement before or after the call to `winsound.MessageBeep()`? Can you see it printing something?

Comment: that's odd, I can't even get the `print hello` example on the Python doc page to work. I've never used multiprocessing but I have used threading. Not sure if that would meet your needs, but it works rather well. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: I changed my code to this and now the only thing on my screen is correct.


    import time
    import winsound
    from multiprocessing import Process
    def pr1():
        while 1:
            winsound.MessageBeep()
            print('its working') 
            time.sleep(0.5)
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print('correct')
        p = Process(target=pr1, args=())
        p.start()
        p.join()

    while 1:
        print('hey')

Comment: Update the code in your question. Nobody can read Python in comments.

Comment: I don't have winsound but this code works for me if I just print something

Comment: updated it to the question

Comment: try extending the time for sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indent the final

```
while 1:
    print('hey')
```

to make it part of the `if`-block

When starting the child process under Windows the module contents are first executed before the callable given as `target` is run. Because the module never finishes execution, this doesn't happen.

The second snippet as a whole then becomes:

```
import time
import winsound
from multiprocessing import Process
def pr1():
    while 1:
        winsound.MessageBeep()
        print('its working') 
        time.sleep(0.5)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('correct')
    p = Process(target=pr1, args=())
    p.start()
    p.join()

    while 1:
        print('hey')
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean. If indent the while statement, northing happens or do I have to move it?

Comment: @CvR_XX If you indent it, it is only executed if the `if`-statement is true (which only happens in parent process). I tried it with your second code snippet and it works for me.

Comment: I could be a little sleepy but I still don't understand can you please post the second snippet with you edits.

Comment: the strange thing is that, even with this code, I only see "correct" and not "hey" and "it's working"

Comment: good job windows, It's suddenly start working causing a lot of noise and a slow pc because of hundreds of python processes

Comment: @CvR_XX Regarding the "hey" output: You won't see this because it is only shown after child process terminates (then `p.join()` returns) which doesn't happen because of the endless loop in `pr1()`. "its working" should show up, though.

Answer (score 0):

To show the "its working" message you need to flush the buffer, because usually in processes the output is normally buffered.

```
import time
import winsound
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys
def pr1():
    while 1:
        winsound.MessageBeep()
        print('its working')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        sys.stdout.flush()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('correct')
    p = Process(target=pr1, args=())
    p.start()
    p.join()
```